# What can we deduce about $A$ and $B$ if $\bar{A} \cap \bar{B} = \bar{A}$?

Tags: general-topology

I suddenly came across with the following problem (or exercise?) in topology that I can not get out of my mind.

Let $A$ and $B$ be non-closed subsets of a (non-discrete) topological space $X$. Suppose $\bar{A} \cap \bar{B} = \bar{A}$, where $\bar{U}$ denotes the closure of $U$ in $X$. Can we say anything about the relationship between $A$ and $B$? Perhaps a more specific question would be: is it possible for $A \cap B$ to be trivial?

I would be grateful for ideas or examples you can share.

Comment: Take $A = \mathbb{Q}$ and $B = \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. Trivial intersection, both dense.